# $R(3,6) = 18$, especially proving that $R(3,6)>17$

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I'm studying the Ramsey numbers, especially $R(3,6) = 18$

I understand that the proof using the theorem $R(m,n) <R(m-1,n)+R(m,n-1)$ can only prove that $R(3,6)<20$. However by Cariolaro's "[On the Ramsey number $R(3,6)$](http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/37/ajc_v37_p301.pdf)" I understand the proof for $R(3,6)<19$.

Now I try to understand the proof for $R(3,6)>17$, but the graph there is built with some program. I read that it is possible to build a graph to test $R(3,6)>17$ without programs.

In "thesis (Ph. D.)--University of Waterloo, 1966, [Chromatic Graphs and Ramsey's Theorem](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015014352580)" by J. G. Kalbfleisch this result supposedly exists, but unfortunately I can not find the document. Can someone give the idea of ​​the construction or do you know of any document or article where you do it?

Comment: Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/how-to-construct-17-vertexed-graph-for-ramsey-number-r3-6-18 will answer your question.

Comment: The thesis can be searched here: https://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015014352580 but without logging in one cannot see even snippet results (and even if you log in, I don't know what you'll get). Other than that, ask for an inter-library loan, if it is possible.

Comment: the thesis has been digitized by [HathiTrust](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000420860) but only limited search is available because of copyright restrictions. I presume this means there is no (legal) online copy and borrowing a print version is the only option.